Power Query - Filtered Rows
I have a Powery Query loading from an external spreadsheet. I would like to filter results using #Filtered Rows based on the value of a particular cell on a different sheet.
Example: Sheet 1 has cell value (A1) of "red"
Sheet 2 has power query. Need to filter table using #Filtered Rows if value from Sheet 1 (A1) is red or another color.  Then 'else' to a default filter option.
PLEASE HELP!  MUCH APPRECIATED>
Tried searching the web up and down

In excel, give the cell you want to use in the filter a range name, here aaa.  Then in powerquery, pull the value of that range name (aaa) and filter the the other data (assumed to be Table1) on the contents of that range name
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
CellValue= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="aaa"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Column2] =CellValue)
in #"Filtered Rows"

